# Find the longest substring without any number and at least one upper case character C#

Tags: c#, data-structures

I have to Find the longest SubString without any number and at least one upper case character using c#. If the string is "sdcF01h" then o/p should be "sdcF"
My approach.

```
String testString = "sdcF01F";
//var splitString = testString.Split("[0-9]");
int startIndex = 0;
int longestStartIndex = 0;
int endIndex = 0;
int index = 0;
int longestLength = int.MinValue;
bool foundUpperCase = false;
while (index <= testString.Length)
{
    if (index == testString.Length || char.IsDigit(testString[index]))
    {
        if (foundUpperCase && index > startIndex && index - startIndex > longestLength)
        {
            longestLength = index - startIndex;
            endIndex = index;
            longestStartIndex = startIndex;
        }
        startIndex = index + 1;
        foundUpperCase = false;
    }
    else if (char.IsUpper(testString[index]))
    {
        foundUpperCase = true;
    }
    index++;
}
endIndex--;
var res1 = testString.Substring(longestStartIndex, endIndex);
Console.WriteLine(res1);
```

But this is not the most optimal solution.

Comment: Your proposed answer of sdcF doesn't make sense. That's not a substring. It's just gathering all the lowercase letters (except h for some reason) and one uppercase.

Comment: @mariocatch : Could you please help me out in this case.

Comment: it is better for you to use `Regex`

Comment: @FSm : Please guide as I am not very fluent in regx.

Comment: @PiyushSing you need to better define your requirements. They don't make sense at the moment as I stated.

Comment: First, the problem as stated doesn't make any sense; why is sdcF the solution and not sdchF -- if by substring you mean "a string composed by removing one or more characters from the original string" -- or just F, if you mean "a string composed by taking a contiguous subsequence of the original string".

Comment: Second, this is not even a question! What is your *specific question* about this code?  If the question is "can someone do my homework for me?", well, that's not what StackOverflow is for. People will be happy to help you, but you should ask a *specific* question about something you don't understand.

Comment: Hey @ Eric Lippert  : I myself  changed the approach and gave the answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
   var abc= Regex.Matches("co12dEname123abP", @"[a-zA-Z]+|\d+")
.Cast<Match>()
.Select(m => m.Value)
.ToArray();
    List<string> lst = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < abc.Length; i++)
    {
        if (abc[i].Any(char.IsDigit))
            continue;
        if (abc[i].Any(c => char.IsUpper(c)))
            lst.Add(abc[i]);
    }
    var finalOutput =lst.OrderByDescending(x => x.Length).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is problem in your question example:

> if the string is "sdch01F" then o/p should be "sdcF" My approach.

The right should be result is **F**.
I suppose you mean that "sdc**F**01F" the result is "sdcF" (like in the your code example).

Any way this is my solution*:

```
private string GetLongestSubstring(string testString)
{
    var longestSubstring = string.Empty;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(testString))
    {
        return longestSubstring;
    }

    var rg = new Regex("[A-Z]");
    var currentSubstring = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < testString.Length; i++)
    {
        var currentChar = testString[i];
        var isValidChar = !char.IsDigit(currentChar);
        if (!isValidChar)
        {
            var newSubstring = currentSubstring;
            currentSubstring = string.Empty;

            var matches = rg.Match(newSubstring);
            var iscurrentSubstringContainsAtLeastOneCapitalLetter = matches.Success;
            if (iscurrentSubstringContainsAtLeastOneCapitalLetter)
            {
                if (longestSubstring.Length < newSubstring.Length)
                {
                    longestSubstring = newSubstring;
                }
            }
            continue;
        }

        currentSubstring += currentChar.ToString();
    }

    if (currentSubstring.Length > longestSubstring.Length)
    {
        longestSubstring = currentSubstring;
    }

    return longestSubstring;
}
```

- Note, the function takes into account that there is no space (" ") in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Just split, sort on length, and test for upper

```
public static string GetSubset(string input = "LKAH8slfsfjlllj9lkjlkjasdf;lk7ljasdflkasdjsfdljk")
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        return string.Empty;
    foreach(String s in input.Split(new Char[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Length))
    {
        foreach (char c in s)
            if (char.IsUpper(c))
                return s;
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```